# selenium opens application with 8002 instead 4444 on Windows 8-IE10

Tags: windows-8, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-10

I am running a simple java selenium test that opens an app `http://localhost:8000/` but when selenium opens the application in IE10 it opens with 8002 port instead of 4444. Because of this it always leads to 404 error and when I change the port to 4444 the test proceeds fine.
This is happening only with IE10 on Windows 8. Other browsers (chrome/firefox) seem to run the test correctly on Windows 8.

I am using latest selenium v2.25.0. This is webdriver backed selenium but I am using legacy selenium apis (ex: `selenium.open()`)

Anybody have suggestions on how to debug this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well for a starter, I'd like to point out v2.25 is from July last year - you should be keeping with the latest versions, so update to v2.31 and try again!

Comment: Tried with latest jar, still same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can feed a port parameter to selenium when you are initializing it:

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, '*firefox', siteUrl);
```

Comment: I already have it initialized to 4444 port , I see that in logs as well. It appears that its a selenium bug https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=525